# pandas dataframe slicing to a subset from row #y1 to row #y2

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, slice

I can't see the forest for the trees right now:

I have a Pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.DataFrame({'UTCs': [32776, 32777, 32778, 32779, 32780, 32781, 32782, 32783],
                   'Temperature': [5, 7, 7, 9, 12, 9, 9, 4],
                   'Humidity': [50, 50, 48, 47, 46, 47, 48, 52],
                   'pressure': [998, 998, 999, 999, 999, 999, 1000, 1000]})
print(df)
    UTCs  Temperature  Humidity  pressure
0  32776            5        50       998
1  32777            7        50       998
2  32778            7        48       999
3  32779            9        47       999
4  32780           12        46       999
5  32781            9        47       999
6  32782            9        48      1000
7  32783            4        52      1000
```

Now I want to create a subset of all dataset columns for UTCs between 32778 and 32782

I can chose a subset with:

```
df_sub=df.iloc[2:7,:]
print(df_sub)
    UTCs  Temperature  Humidity  pressure
2  32778            7        48       999
3  32779            9        47       999
4  32780           12        46       999
5  32781            9        47       999
6  32782            9        48      1000
```

But how can I do that with the condition like 'chose rows between UTCs=32778 and UTCs=32782'?

Something like

```
df_sub = df.iloc[df[df.UTCs == 32778] : df[df.UTCs == 32783], : ]
```

does not work.
Any hint for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`between`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) for [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df_sub = df[df['UTCs'].between(32778, 32783, inclusive='left')]
```

output:

```
    UTCs  Temperature  Humidity  pressure
2  32778            7        48       999
3  32779            9        47       999
4  32780           12        46       999
5  32781            9        47       999
6  32782            9        48      1000
```

Comment: @Swawa does kind of look like you should consider making `UTCs` the index - especially if it's already sorted as that'd enable efficient normal look ups... eg: `df.loc[32778:32782]`

Comment: @JonClements would that also work if UTCs is not integer? UTCs are values with 3 digits after the comma. Do I then have to specify the decimal places in `df.loc[]` ?

Comment: @Swawa it should do...